# ¿Cómo hacer para que en caso de que la consulta sea null, no me muestre el registro, en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando la consulta traiga como resultado "vacío" o nulo, sencillamente no me traiga nada...
Este es mi Query:

```
select IF (SUM(amount) = 0, null, SUM(amount)) as 'total', cc.name as 'currency', p.srvtype from p2p p, p2p_response t, currency cc, company c, subscription sub, user u where t.p2pid = p.p2pid and u.userid = p.userid and p.currencyid=cc.currencyid and u.companyid = c.companyid and sub.companyid = u.companyid and sub.companyid = c.companyid and c.companyid=1 and sub.serviceid=2 and sub.statusid=3 and STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') = CURDATE() and (t.referenceNumber != 'null' and t.referenceNumber != '');
```

En esa consulta el resultado es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debe ocurrir es que no traiga nada, ni null...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solución rápida: un SELECT de ese SELECT, donde el WHERE tenga en cuenta que el resultado no sea nulo.

Comment: No entiendo pero si entiendo, ¿podrías hacer un ejemplo sencillo para captarlo mejor? gracias.

Comment: ¿Sabés lo que es una subconsulta en un `FROM`? Podés empezar por ahí :) Otra idea es usar un _CTE_ (con `WITH`).

Comment: Intenta añadiendo al final `HAVING total is not null`.

Answer (score -1):

Se puede modificar la consulta para que no devuelva nada si el resultado es nulo agregando la palabra clave "IS NULL" en la cláusula WHERE, así:

```
SELECT IF (SUM(amount) = 0, null, SUM(amount)) as 'total', cc.name as 'currency', p.srvtype 
FROM p2p p, p2p_response t, currency cc, company c, subscription sub, user u 
WHERE t.p2pid = p.p2pid 
AND u.userid = p.userid 
AND p.currencyid=cc.currencyid 
AND u.companyid = c.companyid 
AND sub.companyid = u.companyid 
AND sub.companyid = c.companyid 
AND c.companyid=1 
AND sub.serviceid=2 
AND sub.statusid=3 
AND STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') = CURDATE() 
AND (t.referenceNumber != 'null' 
AND t.referenceNumber != '')
AND SUM(amount) IS NOT NULL;
```

Esto filtrará las filas en las que el resultado de SUM(cantidad) sea nulo y, por lo tanto, no devolverá ningún dato si el resultado es nulo.

Comment: Me dice

#1111 - Invalido uso de función en grupo


Me ayudaria mas si logras que esta tabla:
CREATE TABLE `tabla` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` varchar(50), 
`description` varchar(35),
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)

Al realizar esta consulta no arroje nada en lugar de esos NULL

SELECT IF (SUM(amount) = 0, null, SUM(amount)) as 'amount', description FROM tabla WHERE 1=2;

Comment: Hector: las funciones de agregación no funcionan en el `WHERE`, sino en el `HAVING`.

Comment: Padalelaina... gracias.... MUCHAS GRACIAS........ hiciste funcionar el query que me estaba matando

Comment: @CHACRLONANTONIOROMANMARIN soy Padaleiana :) Ponlo entonces como respuesta. De hecho, es casi lo mismo que mencionó _Sal_ como comentario en la pregunta. No olvides hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil (que si la redactas, sería tu caso).

Comment: ¿Cómo escojo la mejor respuesta? ya ustedes me ayudaron.

Comment: @CHACRLONANTONIOROMANMARIN no olvides @ al usuario a quien querés dirigirte, ya que no llegan notificaciones si no mencionás al usuario (podés mencionar solo a un usuario por comentario). Por otra parte: si la respuesta no está presente, _redáctala_. Y no olvides explicar cómo funciona la consulta que te funcionó (y/o qué fue lo que agregaste para que te funcione.)